# Ruby Removing extracting [ "a" , "3" ] from a[3]

Tags: ruby

I am new to ruby and I want to extract `[ "a" , "3" ]` from `"a[3]"`. I am using the following:

```
pin = "a[3]"
a = Array.new
a = pin.split(/\[/)
if a.length == 1
  return a
elsif a.length == 2
  a[1].gsub( /\]/, // )
  return a
else
  raise " Error , Invalid syntax for pin #{pin}. "
end
```

I am getting this error:

```
t:8:in `gsub': can't convert Regexp into String (TypeError)
```

I couldn't understand it.

Comment: So you mean `pin = "a[3]"` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just grab what you want this way:

```
pin = "a[3]"
a = pin.scan(/[A-Za-z0-9]+/)

# => ["a", "3"]
```

This assumes you want consecutive alphanumerics. Adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

The second argument to `gsub` needs to be a string(`""`), not a regex(`//`).